# Input with glyphicon button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create an input that has a button to the right that contains an icon and can be clicked a bit like this

Here is my code so far
http://www.bootply.com/udRtNLsCgV

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Select area...">
    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-edit" onclick="openDialog()"><a href="#">Area</a></span>
</div>
```

My problem is that the font in the button doesn't seem to be the default font and the input is far too wide

Answer (score 0):

1. Include your icon separately (inside div with `input-group-addon` class).
2. You can control width of input group in CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Select area...">
  <span class="input-group-addon" onclick="openDialog()"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Area</a></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-group {
  width: 200px;
}
.input-group-addon > a {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

### [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/4PcJF1IUDx#)